# Table with different number of rows per column and jagged edge?

Tags: tables, formatting

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to create a table in latex that looks something like this?

[image]

I have a table in my project like this one below, but would like to remove the lines for the bottom right half.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*4{c|}}
\hline
1&2&3&4\\
\hline
1&2&3&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
\cline{1-3}
1&2&\multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
\cline{1-2}
1&\multicolumn{3}{c}{}\\
\cline{1-1}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There has been an answer. This answer is to show what is the effect of `\cline` and `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}`. And I suggest you to put a minimum working example when asking a question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
Normal tabular\\[1em]
\begin{tabular}{|*3{c|}}
\hline
  a & b & c\\
\hline
  d & e &\\
\hline
  f &   &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\[1em]
Tabular using \verb|\cline|\\[1em]
\begin{tabular}{|*3{c|}}
\hline
  a & b & c\\
\hline
  d & e &\\
\cline{1-2}
  f &   &\\
\cline{1-1}
\end{tabular}\\[1em]
Tabular using \verb|\cline| and \verb|\multicolumn|\\[1em]
\begin{tabular}{|*3{c|}}
\hline
  a & b & c\\
\hline
  d & e & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
\cline{1-2}
  f &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{red}\vrule width 2pt}}{}\\
\cline{1-1}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]